# How to store information persistently in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have an application which loads a list of countries in a tableview. First time when the app is downloaded it should display the entire list, when the user selects a country this should be added to an array. I'm not getting how to track how many number of countries user has selected for the first time and from next time whenever the user open the app I should display only the selected countries. In what way can I implement this? When I searched in net got to know static but unable to implement it.

I'm new to iPhone development. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options to store information persistently: Core Data, SQLite, etc. A simple one to use in this case is NSUserDefault. If you keep the list of selected countries in an NSArray you can store and retrieve this array as follows:

```
//To set your array
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:(NSArray *)yourArray forKey:@"userSelection"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

//To retrieve your array
NSArray *myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"];
```

To use this option your NSArray however must be a property list - here's the Apple documentation to learn what a [property list is](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html). If you want to store other type of objects you should look into different solution (.e.g Core Data).

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the selection persistently. Nothing to do with a static variable, which would get nulled when quitting the app. Look for example at [`NSUserPreferences`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html) as one way to store user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `persistent storage`.

The various ways of `persistent storage` in `iOS` are:-

1. `Property Lists`
2. `SQLite`
3. `Core Data`
4. `User Defaults (NSUserDefaults)`.

Depending on the kind & size of data you want to store, one of the following could be used.

If your requirement says that you only have to persist a `NSArray`, then it is a good idea to go for `Property Lists` or `NSUser Defaults`.

For reading & writing `Property List` you can find the documentation [in Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1)

For `NSUser Defaults` usage, you can find a good tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)